# How can I get html from selection in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This should be a simple question, but I'm having some trouble on it.

I have this code:

```
function getSelectionHtml() {
    var html = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("span");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    }

    return html;
}
```

This code returns my HTML, with one caveat. If I have this code

```
<span text-decoration="underline">word 01</span> test02
```

I have different results for different selections.

If I select "01 test02" I'll get:

```
<span text-decoration="underline">01</span> test02
```

but if I select "ord", I'll get

```
ord
```

and I want to get

```
<span text-decoration="underline">ord</span>
```

how can I do that? Javascript only, if possible.

Edit 01:

- I'm on Safari on a Mac. I don't need a cross-browser solution
- the resulting code is not exactly as shown; but the main idea remains: span style is just shown if selection has styled and not styled part

Comment: `getSelection()` includes the full HTMLElement that is selected. So in case of `ord` being selected, the tags are not included because you did not include them in the selection. While the results _**appear**_ to be different, they truly reflect what you've selected (including or excluding selected tags).

Comment: hum, I see, @RandyCasburn . Needless to say, I need the results to be as defined...

Comment: I know you can do this, but the API is very new. For instance, there is an `extend()` method on the Selection Object. Just can't get it to work for you.

Comment: Just identify that current selection doesn't contain tags (ie `html[0] != '<'` ) and then use `commonAncestorContainer` to eventually get the above tag.